# How to change TypeScriptToolsVersion from 3.7 to 3.8

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am developing a project in VS2019. When I compile it, I receive the following warning:

```
warning : Your project specifies TypeScriptToolsVersion 3.7, but a matching compiler was not found. The latest available TypeScript compiler will be used (3.8). To remove this warning, install the TypeScript 3.7 SDK or update the value of TypeScriptToolsVersion.
```

I was trying to find where TypeScript version is specified but I did not find it. Microsoft.TypeScript.targets does not define it, however, if it would, I think I could change the value by not modifying that file directly.

Where can I fix that?

Jaime

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look for TypeScriptToolsVersion tags in your csproj files and update to required version.

Comment: Looking in my `.csproj` file now and it doesn't exist. `:-(`

Answer (score 12):

Go to your project Properties -> "TypeScript build" tab and in the field: "TypeScript version" either choose specific version or select "Use latest available"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@BogdanRB answer above only displayed "Use latest available" and "4.2" for me. I did some research and apparently "4.2" is the SDK version installed together with Visual Studio 2019 (which I couldn't remove since it's required for lots of other VS components).

I was working on a legacy project that uses TypeScript "3.1.1", the version specified in `package.json` installed via npm. In order to line up the editor's IntelliSense and the compilation, and avoid using unsupported TS syntax, I've opened my ASP.NET Core MVC `.csproj` file and removed the following line:

`<TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`

Now Visual Studio's IntelliSense is compatible with the one specified in the npm package. It even works inside `*.vue` templates, in case you're using Vue with TypeScript.